# Send some data to a url using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am having problems with sending some data to a url using jquery. The idea is this, in my index.php page I have functions that allow me to login, registrater, and return data as a json. If "tag" is equal to login then the user logs in and if it's equal to sign will be sign in. My problem is that I'm new at jquery and I can't see the error in my code that won't allow it to register users.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#register").submit(function(){
          $.post("http://localhost/aplicacion/", { 
              tag: "register", 
              u_name: "John", 
              email: "john@mail.com", 
              password: "rob" 
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

In this code I sent all the data without regard to what is filled in the form and without the part where I contemplate the data returned in the json because i did it little by little and I wanted to see if it worked ... but it doesn't.

Edit: the functions in index.php works (I'm developing an android application in parallel and it uses the same system for signin and logging users and it works).

Comment: Check your browser tools, specifically the console and network tabs. Are there any errors?

Comment: I would recommend aJax for thjis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return false;` after `$.post(...)` call if you don't want the form to proceed with default submit.